# SparkSql Hive in Local Mode unable to parse constants in query

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run spark in local mode for writing tests. I am using Hive support in SparkSql for some queries in code.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local")
  .setAppName("Test")
  .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false");

javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
hiveContext = new HiveContext(javaSparkContext.sc());

File directory = Files.createTempDir();
hiveContext.sql("DROP TABLE prefixes");
hiveContext.sql("Create EXTERNAL table prefixes (prefix string) LOCATION \""+ directory.getAbsolutePath()+"\"");
```

When i query the table "prefixes" with where clause

```
hiveContext.sql("Select prefix from prefixes where prefix = '94C'");
```

it fails with following error

```
Unsupported language features in query: select prefix from prefixes where   prefix = '94C'

TOK_QUERY 1, 0,14, 19
  TOK_FROM 1, 4,6, 19
    TOK_TABREF 1, 6,6, 19
      TOK_TABNAME 1, 6,6, 19
        prefixes 1, 6,6, 19
  TOK_INSERT 0, -1,14, 0
    TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
      TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
        TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
    TOK_SELECT 1, 0,2, 7
      TOK_SELEXPR 1, 2,2, 7
        TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 2,2, 7
          prefix 1, 2,2, 7
    TOK_WHERE 1, 8,14, 52
      = 1, 10,14, 52
        TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 10,10, 45
          prefix 1, 10,10, 45
        '94C' 1, 14,14, 54

scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for ASTNode type: 298, text: '94C' :
'94C' 1, 14,14, 54
" +

org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.nodeToExpr(HiveQl.scala:1558)
          ;
```

Library used in maven

```
<!--Spark Dependencies-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The same code is working on my cluster when i am running on yarn master mode.

Has someone seen such an issue or knows what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

This was because of hive dependency included for Cloudera dist. Moving the above dependencies to top of dependency list solved the issue